# Add attribute to a DOM NodeList node using XSLT

Tags: xslt, attributes, addition

I have to add one attribute Publisher="Penguin" to the nodes from a NodeList : The input xml looks like:

```
    <Rack RackNo="1">
    <Rows>
    <Row RowNo="1" NoOfBooks="10"/>
    <Row RowNo="2" NoOfBooks="15"/>
    <Rows>
    </Rack>
```

The output xml lookslike:

```
   <Rack RackNo="1">
    <Rows>
    <Row RowNo="1" NoOfBooks="10" Publisher="Penguin"/>
    <Row RowNo="2" NoOfBooks="15" Publisher="Penguin"/>
    <Rows>
    </Rack>
```

The xsl i wrote is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
        <Order>
            <xsl:copy-of select = "Rack/@*"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Rows/Row">
                    <OrderLine>
                        <xsl:copy-of select = "Row/@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="Publisher"></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:copy-of select = "Row/*"/>
                    </OrderLine>
                </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select = "Rack/*"/>
        </Order>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This doesnt return the desired output. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for the XSLT identity transform. On its own it simple creates a copy of all the nodes in your input XML

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

All you need to do is add an extra template to match **Row** element, and add a **Publisher** attribute to it. It might be good to first parameterise the publisher you wish to add

```
<xsl:param name="publisher" select="'Penguin'" />
```

You then create the matching template as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
   <OrderLine Publisher="{$publisher}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </OrderLine>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of "Attribute Value Templates" to create the **Publisher** attribute. The curly braces indicate it is an expression to be evaluated. Also note in your XSLT it looks like you are renaming the elements too, so I have done this in my XSLT as well. (If this is not the case, simply replace **OrderLine** back with **Row**.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="publisher" select="'Penguin'" />

   <xsl:template match="Rack">
      <Order>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </Order>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Rows">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Row">
      <OrderLine Publisher="{$publisher}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </OrderLine>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<Order>
   <OrderLine Publisher="Penguin" RowNo="1" NoOfBooks="10"></OrderLine>
   <OrderLine Publisher="Penguin" RowNo="2" NoOfBooks="15"></OrderLine>
</Order>
```